# how to draw add_line from matplotlib to subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image]

the matplotlib subplot doesn't show any graph while trying to add_line with my data.

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)

for csv in tqdm(csv_files):
    temp_csv = pd.read_csv(csv)[csv_features]
    plt.sca(ax1)
    plt.gca().add_line(plt.Line2D(range(262), temp_csv["내부 온도 1 최저"][:262], color=color[risk]))
    plt.sca(ax2)
    plt.gca().add_line(plt.Line2D(range(262), temp_csv["내부 온도 1 최저"][:262], color=color[risk]))
```

I want to make the upper codes work.

Comment: When using functions such as `add_line` matplotlib doesn't automatically adjust the datalimits of the axes. The recommended approach uses `ax1.plot(...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be jumping through hoops here.  Does

```py
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
ax1.plot(range(262), x[:262], color=color[risk])
ax2.plot(range(262), y[:262], color=color[risk])
```

(where x and y are replaced by whatever you want to plot) not work for you?

Comment: the reason I need to use add_line is to stack multiple lines to each ax1 and ax2 in further works

Comment: I don’t understand this comment.  What is preventing you from calling `ax1.plot()` more than once?

Comment: I tried with ax1.plot to for loop and it stacks lines, working exactly what I wanted. thanks